# Loading Two Custom Fonts in Material UI ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am currently making use of Material UI ReactJS library for a React App but using Typescript instead of core Javascript.

I have a little issue that I haven't being able to figure out.

I have two typefaces that I wish to use in my react app, namely:
**Circular-Std** and **Inter**.

How can I use these two typefaces in the Material UI ReactJS library with Typescript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For add customs font just add this inside your theme.js :

```js
 typography: {
    fontFamily: ["Lexend Deca", "sans-serif"].join(","),
  },
```